# why do i need wait after assert in VHDL?

Tags: testing, vhdl

I've started learning VHDL, and on EdaPlayground there's always a `wait;` after `assert(cond);` in the testing file.

Could you please explain why do i need a `wait;` in the end? From my point of view, it should terminate right after execution, but it doesn't (and instead of terminating it lands into an infinite loop).

Here is the architecture i want to test :

```
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity minority is
port(
  a: in std_logic;
  b: in std_logic;
  c: in std_logic;
  y: out std_logic
  );
end minority;

architecture impl of minority is
begin
   y <= '1' when (a and b and c) else '0';
end impl;
```

Here is the code for testing :

```
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
 
entity testbench is
-- empty
end testbench; 

architecture tb of testbench is

-- DUT component
component minority is
port(
  a: in std_logic;
  b: in std_logic;
  c: in std_logic;
  y: out std_logic
  );
end component;

signal a1, b1, c1, y1: std_logic;

begin
  -- Connect DUT
  DUT: minority port map(a1, b1, c1, y1);

  process
  begin
    a1 <= '0';
    b1 <= '1';
    c1 <= '0';
    y1 <= '0';
    wait for 1 ns;
    assert(y1='0') report "Y is ok." severity error;
    wait; -- <-- without this line, the test starts to execute infinitely :(
  end process;
end tb;
```

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Well, you already seem to know why. Without the `wait;` the process keeps repeating forever.

Comment: There's a good answer here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/193682/why-is-there-a-wait-at-the-end-of-a-vhdl-test-case

Comment: @mkrieger1 thank you a lot!

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.3 Process statement "The execution of a process statement consists of the repetitive execution of its sequence of statements. After the last statement in the sequence of statements of a process statement is executed, execution will immediately continue with the first statement in the sequence of statements." 10.2 Wait statement "If no timeout clause appears, the timeout clause for (STD.STANDARD.TIME'HIGH – STD.STANDARD.NOW) is assumed." 14.7.5.3 Simuilation cycle "Simulation is complete when Tn = TIME'HIGH ..."

Answer (score 0):

VHDL is a **hardware** description language. The VHDL `process` is a key part of it. Hardware doesn't just stop. Therefore, VHDL processes don't just stop, either; they keep on going, just like hardware does.

If you want to use a process for something other than hardware design (ie you are not going to synthesise it) and you want it to only run once, then you are going to have make it stop. You do that by adding a `wait` statement, because in VHDL, a `wait` on its own means *wait forever*.

Comment: It will be good to mention that `wait` is not synthesizable.

Comment: Any concurrent statement either implies design hierarchy, elaborated processes or both. A process without a wait statement will not suspend and simulation time will not advance. A wait statement can be implied by a sensitivity list, or signal evaluations. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.3 Process statement, 10.2 Wait statement "The wait statement causes the suspension of a process statement or a procedure." and 14.7.5.3 Simuilation cycle.